# Homeomorphism with dense set of fixed point

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

In my research I need to construct a metric space $(X, d)$ with a dense subset $Y\subseteq X$ such that for every homeomorphism $f:X\to X$ we have $f(y)=y$ for all $y\in Y$. In the following I constructed such a metric space. Please help me to determine whether my idea works or still has some mistakes.

Let $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0, 1]$ and $$X=\cup_{x\in [0, 1]}(\cup_{a\in A}(x, a)\times (a, x)).$$ Consider $(a, a)\in X$ and a homeomorphism $f:X\to X$. Then take an sufficiently small open connected ball $U$ around $(a,a)$ such that $U\setminus\{(a, a)\}$ has four connected components. Since $f$ is a homeomorphism, hence $f(a, a)= (a, a)$.

Comment: So you want a metric space whose only self-homeomorphism is the identity?

Comment: @Gae.S., I need a metric space $X$ with a dense subset $A\subseteq X$ s.t for  every homeomorphism $f$, unnecessary identity map, we have $f(a)=a$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: Yeah, but if $f:X\to X$ is continuous, $X$ is Hausdorff, $\left.f\right\rvert_A=\left.id\right\rvert_A$ and $A$ is dense, then $f=id$.

Comment: An example of such a space, likely the only one, is a single point space.

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/188762) gives the construction of a *rigid* (i.e. the homeomorphism group is trivial) infinite metric space.

Comment: As far as your idea goes, the way I see it your $X$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R^2$, and therefore it is not rigid, because in fact all its connected components will be homogeneous.